# Price aside, why ever choose Google Cloud Bigtable over Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

If I have a use case for both huge data storage **and** searchability, why would I ever choose Google Cloud Bigtable over Google Cloud Datastore?

I've seen a few questions on SO and other sides "comparing" Bigtable and Datastore, but it seems to boil down to the same non-specific answers.

Here's my current knowledge and my thoughts:

> Datastore is more expensive.

In the context of this question, let's forget entirely about pricing.

> Bigtable is good for huge datasets.

It seems like Datastore is, too? I'm not seeing what specifically makes Bigtable objectively superior here.

> Bigtable is better than Datastore for analytics.

How? Why? It seems like I can do analytics in Datastore as well, no problem. Why is Bigtable seemingly the unanimous decision industry-wide for analytics? What value do GMail, eBay, etc. get from Bigtable that Datastore can't provide?

> Bigtable is integrated with Hadoop, Spark, etc.

Is Datastore not as well, considering it's built on Bigtable?

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085326/google-cloud-bigtable-vs-google-cloud-datastore), this statement was made in an answer:

> Bigtable and Datastore are extremely different. Yes, the datastore is build on top of Bigtable, but that does not make it anything like it. That is kind of like saying a car is build on top of [car] wheels, and so a car is not much different from wheels.

However, this seems analogy seems nonsensical, since the car (including the wheels) intrinsically provides more value than just the wheels of a car by themselves.

It seems at first glance that Bigtable is strictly worse than Datastore, only providing a single index and limiting quick searchability.  What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest considering Cloud Spanner and Firestore in the mix as well.  I would suggest thinking about price/performance for 100K+ operations per second when making comparisons.

Comment: I also looked at Firestore, and definitely throw that in as well. I didn't necessarily consider Cloud Spanner because it's a relational database. At 100K ops/second, price definitely comes into play, but the use case here would probably never exceed 500-1000 ops/second, and the price between the two stores is pretty similar.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Bigtable and Datastore are optimized for slightly different use-cases, and offer different tradeoffs. The main ones are:

**Data model:**

- Bigtable is a wide-column database -- think HBase and Cassandra
- Datastore is a document database -- think MongoDB
- Note that both of these can be used for key-value use cases

**Cost model:**

- Bigtable charges per provisioned nodes
- Datastore is serverless and charges per operation

**In general, Bigtable is a good choice if you need:**

- Fast point-reads and range scans (especially at scale). Bigtable will offer lower latency for key-value lookups, as well as fast scans of contiguous rows - a powerful tool since rows are stored in lexicographic order. If you have simple, predictable query patterns and design your schema well, reading from Bigtable can be incredibly efficient.
- High throughput writes (again, especially at scale). This is possible in part because Bigtable is eventually consistent - in exchange you can see big wins in price/performance.

Example use-cases that are great for Bigtable include time series data (for IoT, monitoring, and more - think extremely write heavy workloads and massive amounts of data generated over x units of time), analytics (think fraud detection, personalization, recommendations), and ad-serving (every microsecond counts).

**Datastore (or Firestore) is a good choice if you need:**

- Query flexibility: Datastore offers document support and secondary indexes.
- Strong consistency and/or transactions: Bigtable has eventually consistent replication and does not support multi-row transactions.
- Mobile SDKs: Datastore and Firestore are incredibly well-integrated with firebase ecosystem.

Example use-cases include mobile and web applications, game state, user profiles, and product catalogs.

To answer a few of your questions explicitly:

- **Why is Bigtable used for analytics?** It's mostly about performance: analytics use-cases are more likely to have large datasets and require high write throughput. It's a lot easier to run into the limits of a database if you're storing clickstream data, as opposed to something like user account information. Fast scans are also important for analytics use-cases: Bigtable allows you to retrieve all of the information you need about a user or a device extremely quickly, which you can process in a batch job or use to create recommendations and analysis on the fly.
- **Is Bigtable strictly worse than Datastore?** Datastore definitely provides more built-in functionality like secondary indexes and document support, and if you need those features, Datastore is a fantastic choice. But that functionality comes with tradeoffs. Bigtable provides perhaps lower-level, but incredibly performant APIs that allow users to make those tradeoffs for themselves: If a user values, say, write performance over secondary indexes, Bigtable is an excellent option. You can think of it as an extremely versatile and powerful infrastructural building block. I actually like the wheel/car analogy: sometimes you don't want the car -- if what you really need is a dirt bike, a set of solid wheels is much more useful :)

Comment: "Bigtable is eventually consistent" --
It is not true. Bigtable is strongly consistent unless cluster replication is used.

Comment: Fair enough! Bigtable is strongly consistent within a zone and eventually consistent between zones— but most of the time users are comparing consistency models when replication is enabled!