# Cloud Bigtable : Regional or Zonal Service

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-bigtable

Is Bigtable a Zonal or a regional service? I read that Bigtable is a Zonal service and then i see that Regional Replication for Bigtable is in GA now.
And what is the difference between Bigtable and Datastore, i saw that Bigtable is kind of IaaS and Datastore is fully managed, can anyone please lay out the differences between these two, it's a bit confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out Cloud Bigtable supports [Regional Replication](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/cloud-bigtable-regional-replication-now-generally-available).

This makes the data distribution in BigTable regional.

Regarding your question about the differences of Cloud Bigtable and Datastore I found a very nice [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085326/google-cloud-bigtable-vs-google-cloud-datastore) addressing the differences between the two and I believe that will address your question.